# Grails 2.4.4 - Includes Guava, I need guava 14.x or newer

Tags: grails, dependencies, guava, buildconfig

How does one go about, excluding Grails provided libraries from projects that require later versions of certain libraries?

An example I have is the need to use a later version of Guava. Grails or Intellij include it from $GRAILS_HOME/libs.

> $ find . -name *.jar|grep guava
>   ./lib/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-10.0.1-javadoc.jar
>   ./lib/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-10.0.1.jar
>   ./lib/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-10.0.1-sources.jar

I thought I could exclude it by using a block like this. But it didn't work. I had to delete it from the Grails lib folder. After deleting the library, the Guava class collisions ended, which is not a good long term fix.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  // inherit Grails' default dependencies
  inherits("global") {
    excludes 'com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1'
  }
}
```

So, is there a "Best Practice", for handling provided dependency conflicts in Grails?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I just created a new Grails 2.4.4 project and I don't see any usage of guava when I run 'grails dependency-report'. Are you sure a plugin or other dependency isn't including it?

Comment: Work out which dependency its coming from (`grails dependency-report`), then exclude it from that declaration in BuildConfig.groovy.